# Botium-Core - Need to assert only certain parts of alexa response

Tags: javascript, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

**Actual response in Alexa**

> Me : Give my plan details
>
> Alexa : You've enrolled in creditlock yearly plan worth $78 .What else would you like to do?

**Convo file**

> Me# : Give my plan details
>
> Bot# : You've enrolled in creditlock , plan worth $ , What else would you like to do?

`I want to assert only the part of info which i've mentioned in the convo file . 
Why I do this because in my application from user to User the plan and its cost changes.So globally i only check for the basic structure of the response message for smoke test purpose`

Answer (score 1):

This can be controlled with the **[SCRIPTING_MATCHING_MODE capability](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/360603/Botium+Configuration+-+Capabilities#SCRIPTING_MATCHING_MODE)**.

In your case, either the *wildcard* or the *regexp* can be used (*wildcard* available starting from Botium Box 1.8).

With *wildcard* you can use an asterisk symbol (*) to use as a wildcard for everything in the convo file.

```
#me
Give my plan details

#bot
You've enrolled in creditlock * plan worth * What else would you like to do?
```

With *regexp*, you have to use full-blown regular expressions for matching - more complicated, but more powerful.

```
#me
Give my plan details

#bot
You've enrolled in creditlock, \w+ plan worth \$[0-9]+ What else would you like to do \?
```

*You have to take care to correctly quote all regexp control characters you want to use as literal characters*

Comment: Thanks Florian. I'll get back to you on this